# How to check progress of an ongoing installation?

Tags: 16.04

I have run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libbz2-1.0 zlib1g zlib1g-dev 
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0.tar.gz
tar -zxf boost_1_58_0.tar.gz 
cd boost_1_58_0/ 
./bootstrap.sh 
sudo ./b2 install
```

And the last one is taking a very long time (A few hours now). Is there a way to, mid-install, check the progress of the installation?

Comment: It shouldn't take longer than a few minutes. What do see in the terminal, the last line? Perhaps the installer is waiting for some user input...

Answer (score 0):

You could start by just issuing

```
top
```

to see if its consuming CPU. You could also trace its PID and then use `strace` to see what it's doing (if anything):

```
ps -eafww|grep b2
sudo strace -e trace=open -p <pid_from_last_command>
```

Another check would be to identify what directory is being edited. Find the parent directory, and then check what (if any) child directories/files are being written or altered.

In any event `boost` does take a long time to install from source, but it also does exist as a package:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: I'm more concerned with it's progress than whether or not it is still working. I would like an Estimated Time to Completion or something, since I can't leave it plugged in where it is all day. (Is there a way to pause it perhaps?)

Comment: You might be able to pause it. Press Ctrl+Z and you should get a shell prompt. Don't close that terminal session or use that terminal session for anything else while you're pausing. Run `fg` in that terminal session to resume. Use `top` in a separate terminal session to verify that things are paused.